# How to delete a RabbitMQ exchange?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

This seems like a very basic operation but I cannot find a way to delete a named exchange in RabbitMQ. I'm running it on Windows and using the command line tools. At this point I would settle for a .NET API call to delete an exchange, if there exists one. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Management plugin is fine, if you don't need to do it programmatically (but your question indicates otherwise).

There is a command in the .NET API to delete the exchange. It's `IModel.ExchangeDelete` - which is also clearly called out in the [API Specification](http://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-quickref.html).

Comment: You're right. That was the intention in the original question (command line or programmatically) and I'm embarassed to say that somehow I completely overlooked ExchangeDelete in the Intellisense. Thanks.

Comment: My follow up question is: In .NET, is there a way to find out if a named exchange exists?

Comment: You have to try declaring it, and if the channel gets closed you know it exists. Stupid, but that's the AMQP spec.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Just use the [Rabbit MQ Management Plugin](http://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html).